# Adding Package in Julia - Frozen

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm just starting to look at Julia (following a tutorial). I tried to do this:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

but the install is stuck on 99.9% and nothing is happening.

```
Cloning default registries into `C:\Users\Alan\.julia`
Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
Fetching: [========================================>]  99.9 %
```

Does anyone know what has gone wrong please?

Running Julia 1.4 on a Windows 10 destop PC btw.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git cloning with libgit2 sometimes get stuck on Windows for some reason. You can probably just abort and try again. You might also have to delete the partial clone at `~/.julia/registries/General` before trying again. If it doesn't work you can try to git clone the registry outside of Julia, e.g. something like

```
$ git -C ~/.julia/registries/ clone https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General
```